# SFTP Client - File Polling At Regular Intervals

Tags: ftp, sftp

We have a need of a SFTP client running on Windows, which automatically polls for a new file on a designated SFTP location (setup in Unix) every x minutes. Can you please help me identifying such a client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows has a tool named "Task Scheduler".

You can write a batch file that attempts to download the file you seek. Then you point-and-click-and-clickity-click until you've informed Task Scheduler you want that batch file run every *n* minutes.

As for a SFTP client you could try PSCP as part of the [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) collection.